# Multi section UITableView using storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am currently writing a game for the iOS platform. In the main menu, I currently show the user a list of games they participate in using a UITableView. I wish to improve this table view by having one section of active games appear on top, and a list of finished games appearing in a separate section below, under a line with a header saying "Finished Games". I have been playing with XCode for a while now, but I can't seem to find out how to do this. By doing:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}
```

all that happens is just I get duplicates of all lines in the table view, and no separator between the two sections.

If anyone could teach me how to, or point me in a direction on the web in which I can learn how to implement something similar to what I described, I'd be very grateful. I am using storyboards in my project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a simple titled header, you'll need to implement [`tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3atitleForHeaderInSection%3a)

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:
    (NSInteger)section {

    switch(section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Active Games";
        case 1:
            return @"Finished Games";
        default:
            return @"";
    }
}
```

If you're looking for something fancier, there are other methods you can use:

- [tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a)
- [tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a)

---

As for filling out the individual rows, you need to look into [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) and [tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3anumberOfRowsInSection%3a)